# How i can print link to product in widget grid if i know his id

Tags: magento

I have this code in widget grid, in this column i have `id` of products. I want print link to product in grid. How i can do that?

I know how i can get product: `$_newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($quote_id);`

```
    $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('magecom_quotes')->__('product_id'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'filter_index'  => 'product_id',
        'index'         => 'product_id',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'truncate'      => 255,
        'escape'        => true,
    ));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below column in your grid

```
   …
    $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
    'header' => $this->__('Product'),
                'align'  => 'center',
                'index'  => 'product_id',
                'width'  => '50px',
                'renderer'  => 'Namespace_Module_Block_Product'
    ));
    …
```

Now we will create the block indicated in the parameter **renderer**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{  

     public function render(Varien_Object $row)
     {
        $productId =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $link='<a href="' . $product->getProductUrl(); . '">'.$product->getName().'</a>';
        return $link;
     }
}
```

check below links help you to create custom column in grid

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

you need to render. (customize in above link instead on image & short description set your product link).

hope this help you